# Any way I can simply this code.

Tags: python

```
cows = ["aaa","aab","aac","aad","aae","aaf","aag","aah","aai"]
h = ["aaa","aab","aac","aad","aae","aaf","aag","aah","aai"]
test1 = []
day1 = []
day2 = []
day3 = []
day4 = []
day5 = []
day6 = []
day7 = []
aaa = []
days = ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5", "Day 6", "Day 7"]
w = ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5", "Day 6", "Day 7"]
print("Here are your cows :")
print(h)
print("You will need to input the total liters the cow has milked during the day starting from cow aaa to aai.")
for x in range(7):
    print(days[0], end = " ")
    days.pop(0)
    cows = h[0:9]
    for x in range(9):
        print("Cow : ", cows[0])
        test1.append(float(input("How many liters did you milk the cow? ")))
        cows.pop(0)
aaa= list(test1)
for x in range(8):
    aaa.pop(1)
for x in range(8):
    aaa.pop(2)
for x in range(8):
    aaa.pop(3)
for x in range(8):
    aaa.pop(4)
for x in range(8):
    aaa.pop(5)
for x in range(8):
    aaa.pop(6)
for x in range(8):
    aaa.pop(7)
aab= list(test1)
for x in range(1):
    aab.pop(0)
for x in range(8):
    aab.pop(1)
for x in range(8):
    aab.pop(2)
for x in range(8):
    aab.pop(3)
for x in range(8):
    aab.pop(4)
for x in range(8):
    aab.pop(5)
for x in range(8):
    aab.pop(6)
for x in range(8):
    aab.pop(7)
aac= list(test1)
for x in range(2):
    aac.pop(0)
for x in range(8):
    aac.pop(1)
for x in range(8):
    aac.pop(2)
for x in range(8):
    aac.pop(3)
for x in range(8):
    aac.pop(4)
for x in range(8):
    aac.pop(5)
for x in range(8):
    aac.pop(6)
for x in range(5):
    aac.pop(7)
```

I'm trying to find a way to simplify the last part so it looks neat and easier for me, and easier to read.
It's the last part thats killing me. aaa= list(test1) ------- aac.pop(7)

Also, can you run it and tell me you're opinions about it? Like what should I add what should I remove. I will do something with those day1 - day7 lists later. Any opinions will be grateful <3.

Thank you guys so much,
Ahmed

Comment: StackOverflowhas a sister Stack Exchange site for *code review*.  This question is more appropriate for *that*  community.  Also, SO does not favor primarily opinion based questions/answers. Welcome.. Please read: [What kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of popping the cows from the list, why not iterate over them instead of recreating the list every day when the cows should stay the same?

```
cows = h[0:9]
for x in range(9):
    print("Cow : ", cows[0])
    test1.append(float(input("How many liters did you milk the cow? ")))
    cows.pop(0)
```

This can be changed to:

```
for cow in cows:
    print("Cow : ", cow)
    test1.append(float(input("How many liters did you milk the cow?")))
```

Also`test1` is already a list. There is no reason to explicitly convert it.
You can simply say

```
aaa = test1
```

As for the last lines, you can do something like this to reduce the number of times you call `range()`:

```
# For this many days
for x in range(8):
    # Pop the value of liters milked from the cows for that day.
    for y in range(5):
        aaa.pop(y)
```

Comment: for cow in cows:
    print("Cow : ", cow)
    test1.append(float(input("How many liters did you milk the cow?")))

Comment: Is the code at the same indentation of the code that was to be replaced?